# How to change the color of a TabBar in Swift? Image as Background in Navigation bar?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to change the color of my TabBar from the default color to a different color? How do I do this programmatically with swift? Also, how do I assign an image as the background for a navigation bar? Sorry if this is an easy question, I'm new to programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let's say if you have a tab bar controller.
you can do something like this in viewDidLoad()

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
```

and for navigation controller image

```
  var image = UIImage(named: "filename")
  self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(image, forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
```

Comment: I tried this, I placed in the viewDidLoad and it didn't work for that page (tab bar was still same default color) but it worked when switching to other tabs, how do I fix this? Thank you for the response!

Comment: how about self.tabBarController?.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blueColor()

Comment: Great! Can you check accept answer button, appreciate it!